# issue regarding uploading .dSYM file into firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

[image][image]
I have downloaded dSYM file from app store connect and uploaded in firestore under my project.It is showing error required, after sometime i tried the same procedure but it is showing the error continuously.Could anyone help me.Thanks in advance